# Is there a way to initialize an Angular Service without DI into controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a [service like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/1DidCn5aHNWAPuQtvxIn?p=preview)

```
function BroadcastClock($interval, $rootScope){
    this.ticker = $interval(function(){
        console.log("Tick");
        $rootScope.$emit('clockTick');
    }, 1000);
}
function ClockService($interval, $rootScope) {
    var clock = new BroadcastClock($interval, $rootScope);
}
```

This does not work unless I change the controller to declare

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, clockService)
```

In more complex situations (say multiple routes) this adds an extra injection for really no reason. What is the better way to handle this?

**Trying to clarify a bit (I don't get the -1 but whatever)**

The problem I have here is that I do not need to initialize the service using an actual controller. This service in fact feeds into multiple controllers. The singleton aspect helps me keep a single clock for all controllers.

However, the controllers themselves do not interact with it only via the proxy of the rootScope broadcast so I don't see the need to inject it into the actual controller.

See the plunker for more info it won't work, however, when you change

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope)
//To
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, clockService)
```

it works fine, we are not "doing" anything with the service except listening for broadcasts so it doesn't make any sense to inject.

Comment: Please tell us what should not be injected into what according to you

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit unclear..Could you elaborate.

Comment: not fully got your points. angular service is designed to be singleton and easily be injected into directive/controller/service anywhere under the module. if you just want a plain object here, just create one by constructor is ok

Comment: since you are using angular services like $interval and $rootScope, and you're declaring your clockService as a service, then you NEED to do DI. otherwise, rewrite your function to not use any angular and you can just declare a global variable/function which will be everywhere.

Comment: Blint I would like to avoid injecting clockService. Or rather have it initialized without needing to inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you instantiate `BroadcastClock`, I think you still should be able to handle it via a service by either exposing it or exposing functions that handles it.

Anyway you can run initializing blocks with `.config()`, at provider injection time, or in your case `.run()` at the beginning at application's run time:

```
app.run(function($interval, $rootScope) {
  var clock = new BroadcastClock($interval, $rootScope);
});
```

Comment: Thank you some sanity not sure why all the downvotes but this makes sense. Still maintains 1 clock and doesn't require injection removing a lot of lines thanks! Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/NKItkc9NVTx3rdtQfpoW?p=preview